# Laravel Firebird - Unable to complete network request to host “localhost”

Tags: laravel, localhost, driver, firebird

Laravel 5.1.45 lts
php 5.6.31
ubuntu 14.04 lts

I need to read a .FDB firebird file, to do this I have uncommented `extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` in `php.ini` and restart

It has always works in previous server, but...

Some days ago, Amazon AWS write me that my server needed a restart.
I did it and since that nothing works more, and I will migrate to another instance.

Other database works (mysql, sqlite), only firebird **don't**

Way tested without success
- Set 777 to file and folder;
- check `phpinfo()` for module firebird (and that's it).

Error look like about path, but file is there! Is the same error if I intentionally write a wrong name.

Maybe something with apache?
Maybe I need also to install Firebird to the server?

My database.php:

```
'firebird' => [
            'driver'   => 'firebird',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => 'E:/programmi/xamp/htdocs/hubble/storage/firebird/'.$nomefdb,
            'username' => 'sysdba',
            'password' => 'masterkey',
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF8'),
        ],
```

[image]

Comment: _"Unable to complete network request to localhost"_ means that the the driver could not connect to a Firebird server on localhost (presumably port 3050, as you didn't specify it). This would mean that Firebird is not running on your machine, if you configured a new machine, then that probably means you will need to reinstall Firebird as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel or some exotics along the connection lines, like antivirus/firewall preventing connection or "localhost" not resolved to loopback net interface

Comment: @Arioch'The Good point, or localhost resolving to [::1] and not to 127.0.0.1 (in the case of older Firebird versions, or older Firebird client versions)